# Force rebuild the SOAP-Header after authenticating

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

My SOAP-Server expects every request to have a valid token in the soap-header to authenticate the soap-client. This token is only valid for a certain period of time, so I have to expect it to be invalid in every call.

I am trying to find a way to force savon to rebuild the SOAP-Header (i.e. use the new auth-token) after I (re)authenticate with the SOAP-Server. I am not sure, if that is either a savon problem or a ruby one. Here is what I have so far.

```
class Soapservice
  extend Savon::Model

  # load stored auth-token
  @@header_data = YAML.load_file "settings.yaml"

  client wsdl: 'locally-cached-wsdl.xml', 
    soap_header: {'verifyingToken' => @@header_data}

  operations :get_authentification_token, :get_server_time

  # request a new auth-token and store it
  def get_authentification_token
    response = super(:message => {
        'oLogin' => {
            'Username' => 'username', 
            'Userpass' => 'password'
        }
    })

    settings = {
      'UserID' => response[:user_id].to_i,
      'Token' => response[:token], 
    }

    File.open("settings.yaml", "w") do |file|
        file.write settings.to_yaml
    end

    @@header_data = settings
  end

  def get_server_time
    return super()
    rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error
      fault_code = error.to_hash[:fault][:faultstring]
      if fault_code == 'Unauthorized Request - Invalide Token'
          get_authentification_token
          retry
      end
  end
end
```

When I call

```
webservice = Soapservice.new
webservice.get_server_time
```

with an invalid Token, it reauthenticates and saves the new Token successfully, but the `retry` doesn't load the new header (the result is an infinite loop). Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you can strip your example down to a minimum working one. This code looks way too tricky to me. I don't understand why you want to 'force' Savon to 'rebuild' the SOAP header? Don't you build the SOAP message before you call your server? I also prefer NOT to use WSDL files in production, but that's just me.

Comment: I tried to strip some things, to make it a little clearer.

Comment: To answer your question: I have to rebuild the header every time the auth-token is invalidated (after a couple of hours). This could even happen during calls, so I need a way to catch that error and recover from it gracefully (i.e. re-auth and retry last call). It looks to me, as if  savon stores the `soap_header` and never builds it again. Or maybe the `retry` is doing something strange

Comment: I think I'm confused by the use of Savon::Model. I never did that. It is yet another language and yet another level of indirection.

Comment: Yes, `Savon::Model` doesn't appear too often on stackoverflow. But I really like the possibility of DRYing up my code since I don't need to add `Savon.client` to every call.

Comment: @jmk `soap_header` is a [global option](http://savonrb.com/version2.html#globals-soap_header) and even though i think it might be possible to solve your problem in a hacky way, i'd rather like you to [open an issue at github](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues?state=open) so this can be solved properly.

@SteffenRoller thank you so much for your support!

Comment: @rubiii thanks for your gem! I [added an issue at github](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added rubiii's [answer from the GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/371#issuecomment-12738511) here for future reference:

```
class Soapservice

  # load stored auth-token
  @@header_data = YAML.load_file "settings.yaml"

  def initialize
    @client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'locally-cached-wsdl.xml')
  end

  def call(operation_name, locals = {})
    @client.globals[:soap_header] = {'verifyingToken' => @@header_data}
    @client.call(operation_name, locals)
  end

  # request a new auth-token and store it
  def get_authentification_token
    message = {
      'Username' => 'username', 
      'Userpass' => 'password'
    }
    response = call(:get_authentification_token, :message => message)

    settings = {
      'UserID' => response[:user_id].to_i,
      'Token'  => response[:token], 
    }

    File.open("settings.yaml", "w") do |file|
      file.write settings.to_yaml
    end

    @@header_data = settings
  end

  def get_server_time
    call(:get_server_time)
    rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error
      fault_code = error.to_hash[:fault][:faultstring]
      if fault_code == 'Unauthorized Request - Invalide Token'
        get_authentification_token
        retry
      end
  end

end
```

rubiii added:

> notice that i removed Savon::Model, as you actually don't need it and i don't know if it supports this workaround.
>   if you look at the #call method, it accesses and changes the globals before every request.